# Which Exception class is the most suitable for flagging excess number of calls to a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, semantics

I have a database connection object, and I want to restrict/enforce max number of calls to it's write operation (function). I have mocked it in tests, and have overridden the write method to monitor calls to it.

However, I am confused about what error to raise when it's called more than the max number allowed (say 2). I've gone through the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) but haven't found anything suitable. (Hence, as it suggests) I have used `RuntimeError` but I am not fully convinced about the message it gives (not the explicit message I display, but the implicit meaning conveyed by the class itself). I feel `AttributeError` to be a far fit, but nothing else come that close to correctness.

Is there any other builtin exception class which is more suitable for this?

Comment: I'd create a custom exception... I am not quite sure why you'd want a builtin though.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Yes, that's my last resort, a pretty common one too. I should have added this line to the question, missed it :).

Comment: @0xc0de: why would you want to count the number of calls? Do you want to run this code on production? Because you are restricting number of calls to a method which would always throw exception after **MAX** number of calls. It will never open this method till you restart the environment again.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply too many arguments to a function you get something like this:

```
TypeError: function-name takes exactly n arguments (m given)
```

So you could do the same to mirror Python.  You should probably be careful when you call `raise` to ensure that your exception string is distinguishable from one raised by Python, otherwise you could mask a genuine `TypeError`.

Opinion on this is divided.  Some say that custom Exception classes are not required.  Personally I think there is a place for them if there could be confusion.  Creating your own Exception is quite easy, all you need is:

```
class MyException(TypeError):
    pass
```

Now you know that any occurrences come from your code, not from Python.  Remember if you put this in a module or a class to prefix with the namespace, e.g. `MyClass.MyException`.